# deploy php code from github to compute engine using GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions, google-compute-engine

I follow this link [github.com/google-github-actions/auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth) for authentication using Workload identity federation which is successful.

Then, using [github.com/google-github-actions/ssh-compute](https://github.com/google-github-actions/ssh-compute) to SSH into GCP compute engine where I got stuck.

Getting following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
"domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
}
}
]
}
}
```

I know it's related to service account/permission issue but still not able to figure out as I have given the right permission.

Here is my action file:

```
name: Deploy PHP to Compute Engine

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
      
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - id: 'auth'
        name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: '${{ secrets.GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER }}'
          service_account: '${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'

      - name: Set up PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: composer install

      - id: 'compute-ssh'
        name: Deploy to Compute Engine
        uses: 'google-github-actions/ssh-compute@v0'
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          zone: ${{ secrets.GCP_ZONE }}
          ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          instance_name: ${{ secrets.GCP_INSTANCE_NAME }}
          command: 'echo Hello world'
```

Please help me to fix the issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: The error sounds like you do not have the `Service Account User` IAM role for the service account assigned to the Compute Engine instance. Which IAM roles are granted to `secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`? Edit your post with those details. A more secure method is to bind that role to the service account instead of the project.

Comment: Hello John, I have service account my-service-acc@<my-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com with following roles: role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin, role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin, role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser.

Answer (score 0):

All of the authorizations around GCP are difficult. 403 permission denied error can also happen because the OAuth token does not have the right scopes, the client doesn't have permission or the API has not been enabled.

You might want to add `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role.

See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator).